# Define objects at the class level or witin mouseMoved()

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection

Here is the scenario.

- Using JTable
- Elaborate code in mouseMoved() Event for the entire table.
- Over 2 dozen objects are defined and instantiated within mouseMoved()
- JTable could have 20+ columns and 1000s of rows.

Due to the size of the JTable, the mouseMoved() event will be execution numerous times and creating the numerous objects. This could easily result in many thousands of objects getting used and discarded as the mouseMoved() event is executed.

Will this cause a potential issue related to garbage collecting or possibly exhibit a memory growth if the JTable is heavily used?

Which is better:

1. Define the objects in the mouseMoved() event and let the garbage collection clean up the objects once the method exits?
2. Define the objects at the class level, instantiate them in mouseMoved() event then set to null before exiting.

Is one option better than the other?

Comment: Here's my advice: Start with the cleanest approach which is easiest to write, read and maintain. Then test and see if the performance is satisfactory. If not, profile the execution to see what takes most time. Then figure out how to optimize it.

Comment: Have not done any profiling. Would you recommend a favorable reference on how to profile and what to look for within the report?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the created objects. 2 dozens of Integers are fine but 2 dozens of Images will be a real problem.

I would add them on JTable level and try to reuse/cache them somehow. E.g. BigDecimal has kind fo constants ZERO, ONE, ONE to avoid permanent recreation of the popular objects. You should add something like this. Mat be some of the objects could be created once and reinitialized from the MouseEvent.

Comment: Most of the objects are swing objects and related to the Table, Columns and Renderers, but there are a few other custom objects.